# Extracting a function body by name with BASH and regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have some automatically generated code from [MATLAB coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html).  I would like to make a script to find my entries out of large file.  I've successfully plowed my way through regex with BASH to get the main function `main\( *([^)]+?)\)`, and then the body with `/\{([^}]+)\}/`; however, I'm having a terrible time glueing those together.  All I need is the function names contained in main().

I realize that this could be a terrible exercise, but the automatically generated code gives me simple functions that looks like:

```
int main(int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  /* Initialize the application. You do not need to do this more than one time. */
  RT_initialize();
  /* Invoke the entry-point functions. You can call entry-point functions multiple times. */
  main_RT();
  /* Terminate the application.  You do not need to do this more than one time. */
  RT_terminate();
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to extract the that function and body, but my regex is poorer than I recalled.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you please clarify your objective by showing the desired output based on the example? Do you want to extract the function names as `RT_initialize()` in the body? Or do you want to extract the `main()` function with its body out of a source file?

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you'd like to do with this information that you're parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to fairly reliably extract the entire function body is to run the code through a formatter first:

```
indent -kr < mymain.c | sed -n 's/^int main(/,/^}/p'
```

[cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/) can give you a function call graph. eg:

```
cflow -d2 mymain.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to some restrictions to being on BSD, the resulting BASH function follows to get the function body from a C source for a function by name.  This was only tested with the well-formatted C code from MATLAB's Coder.

```
function getFunctionInC(){
TMPFILEIDENT="/tmp/indent.$$.tmp" #temp file
indent "$1" $TMPFILEIDENT
cat $TMPFILEIDENT | awk '
BEGIN { state = 0; last = ""; }
    $0 ~ /^'$2'\(/ { print last; state = 1; }
        { if (state == 1) print; }
    $0 ~ /^}/ { if (state) state = 2; }
        { last = $0; }
'
}
```

The formatting is terrible on the outputs, but I can easily pull the function names to dynamically create defines.  Thanks to everyone who read the question.